# multiple knockout validators on an observablearray

Tags: validation, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I tried to define multiple custom validation rules under a observable array, I was referring to https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Custom-Validation-Rules.

Following is my observablearray with the validation calls:

```
    this.WeeklyData = ko.observableArray([]).extend({
    validation: [
        {
            validator : fminIncrements,
            message: 'use 15 min increments'
        },
        {
            validator: ValidateMinMax,
            message: "Invalid min/max value"
        }
    ]
    });

var ValidateMinMax = function (valueArray) {
var check = true;
ko.utils.arrayFirst(valueArray, function (value) {
    if (parseInt(value.Val(), 10) < 0 || parseInt(value.Val(), 10) > 168) {
        check = false;
        return true;
    }
});
return check;
};

var fminIncrements = function (valueArray) {
var check = true;
ko.utils.arrayFirst(valueArray, function (value) {
    if (parseInt(value.Val(), 10) % 15 !== 0) {
        check = false;
        return true;
    }
});
return check;
};
```

when I do this only the first rule fires. I debugged, and it doesn't even hit the second one. Any idea?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe its because you are using the ko.utils.arrayFirst().   If you use the ko.utils.arrayForEach() instead to check for every case then it shouldn't return at the first occurrence.